# Animate remove or multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that removes divs from a container when a button is clicked. This works very well. The problem is I would like the divs to remove them self one by one with a .2 second delay in between. Currently they are simply removed all at once.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uu3egrws/)**

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $('.mydiv').slice(-5).remove();
});
```

The code above will remove 5 divs that have a class of `myDiv` when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)**

```
var count = 0; // counter for counting
var int = setInterval(function() { // store reference in variable to clear interval
  if (++count == 5) // increment and check count
    clearInterval(int); // if count reached 5 clear the interval
  $('.mydiv').last() // get last element
       .remove(); // remove the last
}, 2000);
```

```js
$("span").text($('.mydiv').length);

$("button").click(function() {
  var count = 0;
  var int = setInterval(function() {
    if (++count == 5)
      clearInterval(int);
    $('.mydiv').last().remove();
  }, 2000);
  $("span").text($('.mydiv').length);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: solid thick red;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 300px
}
.mydiv {
  border: solid thin blue;
  margin: 2px;
  background: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
</div>

<p>
  There are <span></span> items
</p>
<p>
  <button>Remove Items</button>
</p>
```

Comment: short, simple and perfect answer.+1

Comment: @steve : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

How is this:

```js
$("span").text($('.mydiv').length);

$("button").click(function() {
  var divs = $($('.mydiv').slice(-5).get().reverse()), // get the last 5 and reverse them so they are removed in the correct order
    counter = 200;  // 200 miliseconds
      
  divs.each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(counter * i).fadeOut(counter, function() { // if you don't want the fadeOut animation, you can change the fadeOut(counter to fadeOut(0,
        $(this).remove();
        $("span").text($('.mydiv').length);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: solid thick red;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 300px
}

.mydiv {
  border: solid thin blue;
  margin: 2px;
  background: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
</div>

<p>
There are <span></span> items
</p>
<p>
<button>Remove Items</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = 0;
$("button").click(function() {
  $('.mydiv').slice(-5).each(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).remove();
    },timer);
    timer += 200;
  })
});
```

This will loop through each div, and set a timeout before removing it. As it loops it adds an additional 200ms to the delay, making them removed at 200ms intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.hide()` and `remove` elements in `callback`

```js
$("span").text($('.mydiv').length);

$("button").click(function() {
  $('.mydiv').slice(-5).hide(500, function() {
    this.remove()
  });
  $("span").text($('.mydiv').length);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: solid thick red;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 300px
}
.mydiv {
  border: solid thin blue;
  margin: 2px;
  background: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
  <div class="mydiv"></div>
</div>

<p>
  There are <span></span> items
</p>
<p>
  <button>Remove Items</button>
</p>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/uu3egrws/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Please update your js function..

```
$(".mydiv").click(function() {
$(this).slice(-2).remove();
$("span").text($('.mydiv').length);
});
```